# Stop redirecting to posts not in a category / duplicate slugs

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I have multiple posts with the same title, e.g.

- /states/new-york
- /cities/new-york
- /counties/new-york

but Wordpress doesn't allow duplicate slugs, so they appear like:

- /states/new-york
- /cities/new-york-2
- /counties/new-york-3

When I managed to allow duplicate slugs, all of these posts loaded on the same page at the same time. The post cities/new-york is about New York City, and the post /states/new-york is about New York State (these are just examples). Obviously none of these posts share categories.

<del>It seems my problem is largely with redirect_canonical(), which will redirect /cities/new-york/ to /states/new-york/, though the second step is failing me.*</del>

A 301 redirect plugin will not suffice, as /cities/new-york/ also belongs to /big-cities/new-york/ and /us-cities/new-york/ and there are at least 60 of these posts.

*edit:This is not the case. Removing the 404 redirect simply allows nonsense urls. It seems wordpress is happy to load /anything-in-the-world53234/new-york/ as long as the slug is correct. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: This should be fixed as of WP 4.2